# how to browse folder inside my project and explorer it

Tags: vb.net

I have a 2form windows application one of them I want to use it like a Cylinder
(Programs and tools) 
I am succeeded to add my file(and his sub folders) to my Resources

I named the button (ExeinfoPe
and these in Event of the button:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Click1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & "ExeinfoPe"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(appPath, My.Resources.ExeinfoPe, True)
Process.Start("ExeinfoPe\")
```

and this is the result is browser came with choose the application extension
and refused to browsed with explorer.exe

how can I explorer this folder who is inside my application
and can I moved in different application directory like (bin-release)

Comment: you do know there wont be a `bin\release` folder when you deploy your app, right?

Comment: No I don't ... I think maybe when I include it by"include to project"

Comment: the up code work 100% and explorer on files such media files (swf-mp4-ect) but I doesn't in case of folder and these is matter to me

Comment: `Process.Start("explorer.exe", fullpathname)`

Comment: Thx Sir ... But my problem is the path of the folder !!! 
Assuming that the path(my project path) on a c disk "c"\myproject/myproject\Resources\ExeinfoPe .... the folder will show up , but Will this steady path after I published my project and installed ?? would you please give an example of fullpathname

Comment: `Dim myPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)`